# Properties of a $3 × 3$ matrix $A$ that contains two equal rows.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

A $3 × 3$ matrix $A$ contains two equal rows. State whether each of the following is true or false.

(a) $A$ has an inverse.

(b) The rows of $A$ are linearly independent vectors.

(c) The determinant of $A$ is equal to zero.

(d) The equation $Ax = b$, where $x = (x1, x2, x3)^T$ and $b = (1, −1, 1)^T$, has no solutions for $x1$, $x2$ and $x3$.

(e) The rows of $A$ form a basis for $R^3$.

(f) The rank of $A$ is $3$.

---

My Attempt:

a) false

b) false

c) true

d) true

e) false

f) false

Is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: Yup correct to me.

Comment: (d) depends on the matrix. If $A$ has two rows of zeros, certainly there are no solutions. But if $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\-1&0&0\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$, then $x=(1,0,0)^T$ works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @kccu stated part (d) is slightly off due to the fact that the solution $({1,-1,1})$  stated also has two equal rows. Besides that your answers are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider
$$A= \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & -1 & 1\\ -1 & -1 & 2\\ 1 & -1 & 1\end{array} \right)$$

and try to solve for $x_1$ in part d.